# Is there a robust way to set a compiler flag in CMake, overriding/replacing another if it exists?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-warnings

I have a global CMakeLists.txt that sets a bunch of global compile options (examples will use MSVC, but it's not exclusive to it, just that cl.exe generates warnings when it encounters flags override), like `add_compile_options(... /W3 ...)`. When, for some target in a subdirectory of that project I want to set `target_compile_options(targetA PRIVATE /W4)`. However, this produces annoying warning `D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/W4'`. Same with other options that are either set by default, or in a top-level CMake file.

Is there some robust way to add a compile option replacing another (if it exists)? I can only thing of a very verbose and ugly `get_target_property`, followed by `string(REGEX REPLACE...` (which might be tricky to get the right regex and not match anything extra and I'm also not sure that this would include all sources that compile options might come from, like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and co) and the `target_compile_options` again. I want something that would be easy to add to each target that'd want to override "global" options (whether they come from the top-level cmake, default flags or some other source).

Comment: "I'm also not sure that this would include all sources that compile options might come from, like CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and co" - No, variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is never added to the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property. If you want to modify flags which comes that variable, then you should manipulate with the variable itself. In CMake there is no way to modify "all flags". "... which might be tricky to get the right regex" - `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property is a **list** of flags. It could be manipulated with `list` command in much easier way, than with regex.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's the thing. The option in COMPILE_OPTIONS might be "conflicting" (by causing an override warning) with the one in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS (or some other variable) or vice versa.

Comment: @Tsyvarev also, I don't see how `list` makes it any easier . You still need the same amount of boilerplate (get stuff into var, modify var, set the stuff back), and in my case I'd still probably need a REGEX (if I want to be a bit more thorough and remove /W[0-9].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to **replace** some compiler options, it is not recommended in CMake.

If you know that in your project all targets require the **same kind** of option (e.g. `/W`) but with **different values** (e.g. `3`, `4`), then you could express the differences via (custom) **target property**, and add the option as **generator expression** which depends on given property.

You may even provide a default value for a target property, so `set_target_properties` will need to be called only for those targets, which requires non-default compile option.

Top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
...
# Define a target property which will contain desired warning level
# for a target (library or executable)
define_property(TARGET PROPERTY MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL
  BRIEF_DOCS "Warning level"
  FULL_DOCS "Warning level for Visual Studio compiler: 1, 2, ..."
  INHERITED # The property will be initialized from the directory property.
)
# Define a **directory** property with the same name
# It will be used via inheritance and provide default value for the target property.
define_property(TARGET DIRECTORY MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL
  BRIEF_DOCS "Warning level"
  FULL_DOCS "Warning level for Visual Studio compiler: 1, 2, ..."
  INHERITED # The property will be initialized from the parent property.
)

# Set default value of the target property
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL 3)

# Add compiler options which depends on the target property
add_compile_options(/W$<TARGET_PROPERTY:MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL>)
```

Any `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# This library will use /W3 option
add_library(foo ...)

# This library will use /W4 option
add_library(bar ...)
set_target_properties(bar PROPERTIES MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL 4)

# Change default to /W2 for all targets defined below
# (including the ones in subdirectories).
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL 2)

# This library will use /W2 option
add_library(baz ...)
```

The approach when a directory property is created with the same name as the target property is massively used by CMake itself. E.g. the command `add_compile_options` affects on `COMPILE_OPTIONS` directory property,
from which the target property `COMPILE_OPTIONS` gets its default value.

Comment: Marking this as an answer since this is a possible solution to this problem and it doesn't seem like there are any better/proper solutions to this.

Comment: This was really helpful, exactly what I was looking to do - although CMake 3.25.1 wouldn't accept it unless I made the change from `define_property(TARGET DIRECTORY MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL`  to `define_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY MY_VS_WARNING_LEVEL`  
It seemed to do the right thing after that, but I'm still somewhat of a CMake novice, so could be misunderstanding/misconfiguring something.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Typically I'd just suggest to either:

- ignore this warning- either just mentally, or literally disable the warning, but in this particular case, I agree that this is quite annoying, and sadly, I assume that disabling `D9025` would probably prevent you from being warned about some things you might actually care to know about.
- rely on / leverage your compiler's behaviour for "overriding" compile options by just adding them instead of replacing them, in accordance with the compiler's behaviour for conflicting option precedence, but in the scenario you described, that's literally the problem- that the compiler is raising a warning when you are doing exactly that.

So I think the answer is no... the final list of compile options for a source file are compiled from a bunch of different places (non-exhaustive list):

- [variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html)
- [variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html)
- [prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) of the subdirectory and all ancestor subdirectories of the target the source file belongs to
- [prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html)
- [prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html)
- [prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html)

To further complicate this, most of these support generator expressions, and [CMake does option de-duplication](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html#option-de-duplication) for a target's "final list of" compile options. Compilers also have various different behaviours for how options take precedence within various categories of conflicting options (though often taking the one farthest to the right. Ex. [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/command-line-warning-d9025)).

So part of the question is- at which level do you know you want to get rid of something and replace it with something else? If things are very clear cut, you may be lucky enough to do what you've suggested and just do some [string](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html) / [list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html) manipulation to chop something out and replace it. Otherwise, you might just get caught up in some misfortune of not being able (not wanting to) to touch something defined at a "higher" level than what you care about because of the effects it would have on other lower levels.

In your particular case where you set a default at the directory level and want to override at the target level, you could try an approach where you express the directory-level option as a generator expression reading from a custom target property, and using some default value if one is not provided. Maybe something along the lines of `add_compile_options("$<$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:MY_WARNING_LEVEL_OPTION_PROPERTY>,"">:${DEFAULT_WARNING_LEVEL},$<TARGET_PROPERTY:MY_WARNING_LEVEL_OPTION_PROPERTY>>")` and then use [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) to set the per-target "overrides".

Comment: Done. However, I still don't think you can disable D9025.